# Using Twilio to respond to an SMS with a http redirect to an external webapp

Tags: twilio

so, when i send a text message to twilio number, i want it to trigger a specific event in the webapp via http POST. For example, by making a http call to the webapp URL (http://webapp.com/triggerA) which it process to trigger an event A in the webapp.

Can I do this with twilio? If,so is there a sample piece of code which I can refer.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question, I think you can do the following.
With Twilio, when you login into here

https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/incoming

You will find a list of your incoming numbers, I am assuming that you have already purchased a number. Once you click on a number in the list, you will find a page that where you can view and set various properties for the number you are looking at.

You will see a header called Messaging. Under that menu you will see a request Url.
you can set this to http://webapp.com/triggera as per your example. you can also choose whether you would like to use a http post or a http get request type.

the link below, will help you further for handling the data that Twilio passes your application.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request

Louis